# jquery Tabs with ajaxOptions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Scratching my head on this one. With jQuery tabs I am attempting to use ajaxOptions to post data to the page before I load it.

So I have a form on the page before my tabs with some input fields. ie,

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
<!-- inputs etc -->
</form>
```

Then my tabs

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Initital content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

ok so now I should be able to serialize my form so when click a tab it should be a post request ie,

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#myform").serialize(),
        error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
            $( anchor.hash ).html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        }
    }
});
```

It does perform the post request but the form data is always empty.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: Where is the `#tabs` element in relation to the `<form>`?

Comment: Tabs are below the form.

Comment: Do you input elements have `name` attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this runs when you first create the tabs:

```
data: $("#myform").serialize(),
```

The data is whatever it was *then*, it's never updated.  The easiest solution here is just to update that data when it's needed, by using the tab's [`select` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select), like this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  select: function() {
    $(this).tabs("option", { ajaxOptions: { data: $("#myform").serialize() } });
  },
  ajaxOptions: {
    type: 'post',
    error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
      $( anchor.hash ).html(
        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
    }
  }
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/q5dbN/), just look in Firebug, etc to see the form data is being updated and sent with each tab AJAX request.